# How do I make the main window to react to a table click

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpopupmenu

I am a new user of Java swing.  I need to  be able to create a popup with row info  when the user clicks on that row.  I managed to incorporate the mouseClick event reaction in my table class, and I have the row info available. How can I notify the main window about the event so it can display the dialog box/popup box?

Comment: Hi Ayelet. It is very difficult to help if you don't post the code in question. Can you edit your question and add the code you are having problems with?

Comment: I edited your code in your previous post; it might guide you to posting readably.

Answer (score 1):

Just call a method on the main window to perform the action

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to handle this:

1) You can have the custom table class have a custom listener on it (Observer Pattern) which it then calls whenever the click occurs

2) You can have the table call a method on the main window - i.e. pass in the main window as part of the construction of the table

3) You can have the main Window register as a listener to the table (i.e. a mouse listener) and have it handle the events instead.

There are others, I am sure.  These are the ones I have seen most often used.  Depending on the size, scope and intent of the software being written, each has it's merits and detriments.  Is this a project for school, a toy being written to learn about Swing, or is it designed to be a longer term, larger project?  If it is the latter, I would recommend looking up Model View Controller (MVC) architecture discussions, as it can make, long term, the maintenance of the code much easier, in my experience.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hints.  I used the second idea, though I couldn't send the window in the table constructor (it doesn't allow it in static functions such as main).  I sent instead the class that handles all the data uploading and editing which is a member of my main window.  And it works...

Comment: @Ayelet: just as a point of note: it is considered good etiquette on the site to select as answered if someone answered your question.  Glad I could help with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
myTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                int index = myTable.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
                popup.add(myMenuAction);
                popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        }
});
```

And then implement an Action `myMenuAction` where you use the `index` from your table.